# How to embed font in LiveCycle Designer XDP form?

Tags: fonts, adobe, livecycle-designer

How can I embed fonts in LiveCycle Designer when I am saving the form as an XDP file without installing the font on my machine? I tried installing the font on my machine, but when opening the same file in other machine the font doesn't show up. How can I embed font in an XDP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot embed fonts in an XDP.  This is not something that the software supports.

Most fonts are not licensed to be embedded anyway (although you can be licensed for embedding if you pay more to the font vendor, most people do not because of the increased cost).

The fonts must be installed on the other machine *and* on the server (if you are rendering the XDP to PDF, PCL or PS using a server).  Licensing fonts for use on a server is also typically more expensive.